# AndroidAnnotations processing fails in IntelliJ because R.java isn't generated

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, android-annotations

I think there's some problem with IntelliJ when it generates the R.java file, which leads to a problem in AndroidAnnotations because it can't resolve the resource id for my layout.

Here's my activity:

```
package com.airlocksoftware.canvastest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;

@EActivity(R.layout.main)
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

What's weird is that even if I comment out the annotation, and do `setContentView(R.layout.main)`, it works fine even though R.java is never imported.

By the way, the layout is just a simple "Hello World". Nothing weird going on there.

No matter what I do, I can't get AndroidAnnotations to generate `CanvasActivity_.java`. My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.airlocksoftware.canvastest</groupId>
    <artifactId>CanvasTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <android.version>4.2.2_r2</android.version>
        <android.platform>17</android.platform>
        <androidannotations.version>2.7.1</androidannotations.version>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>local-repo</id>
            <url>file:///${env.HOME}/.m2/repository</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${android.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <version>${androidannotations.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>${androidannotations.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>${android.platform}</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The annotation processing [set up like shown in this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPrhE.png)

[image: annotation processing]

Basically I setup the processor path to point to the jar files in my local maven repo, as [described here.](http://www.ashokgelal.com/2012/12/setting-up-intellij-idea-12-with-maven-actionbarsherlock-roboelectric-androidannotations/)

The projects sources are set up [like shown in this screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIAA.png)

[image: project sources]

No matter how I make / rebuild the project, nothing ever shows up in gen/aa (and thus I can't reference CanvasActivity_.java) I ran mvn clean install from the project root, which fails with this stacktrace.

```
INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.363s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat May 18 15:53:06 MDT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project CanvasProto: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/matthewbbishop/Clients/proto/CanvasProto/src/main/java/com/airlocksoftware/CanvasProto/CanvasActivity.java:[6,38] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol  : class R
[ERROR] location: package com.airlocksoftware.CanvasProto
[ERROR] /Users/matthewbbishop/Clients//proto/CanvasProto/src/main/java/com/airlocksoftware/CanvasProto/CanvasActivity.java:[11,12] package R does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/matthewbbishop/Clients/proto/CanvasProto/src/main/java/com/airlocksoftware/CanvasProto/CanvasActivity.java:[14,15] package R does not exist
[ERROR] error: Unexpected error. Please report an issue on AndroidAnnotations, with the following content: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.helper.AnnotationHelper.extractAnnotationParameter(AnnotationHelper.java:293)
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.helper.AnnotationHelper.extractAnnotationResIdValueParameter(AnnotationHelper.java:269)
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.helper.IdValidatorHelper.resIdsExist(IdValidatorHelper.java:45)
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.validation.EActivityValidator.validate(EActivityValidator.java:55)
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.validation.ModelValidator.validate(ModelValidator.java:56)
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.validateAnnotations(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:414)
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.processThrowing(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:364)
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.AndroidAnnotationProcessor.process(AndroidAnnotationProcessor.java:341)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:627)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:556)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:701)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:987)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:727)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:353)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:279)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:270)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.Main.compile(Main.java:87)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess0(JavacCompiler.java:551)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compileInProcess(JavacCompiler.java:526)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.compile(JavacCompiler.java:167)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:678)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[ERROR] at com.googlecode.androidannotations.helper.AnnotationHelper.extractAnnotationParameter(AnnotationHelper.java:287)
[ERROR] ... 46 more
[ERROR] Caused by: java.lang.annotation.AnnotationTypeMismatchException: Incorrectly typed data found for annotation element public abstract int com.googlecode.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity.value() (Found data of type int)
[ERROR] at com.sun.tools.javac.model.AnnotationProxyMaker$ValueVisitor$1.generateException(AnnotationProxyMaker.java:243)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:56)
[ERROR] at $Proxy16.value(Unknown Source)
[ERROR] ... 51 more
```

Honestly I'm at a loss now. If anyone has an idea of what to do, that would be amazing. Thanks!

EDIT: here's the stub R.java generated by IntelliJ.

```
/*___Generated_by_IDEA___*/

package com.airlocksoftware.canvastest;

/* This stub is for using by IDE only. It is NOT the R class actually packed into APK */
public final class R {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your `pom.xml` is missing the following:

```
<packaging>apk</packaging>
```

Without this the `R.java` file will not get generated.

Add it to the top of your `pom.xml` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.airlocksoftware.canvastest</groupId>
    <artifactId>CanvasTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    /* ... */
    /* rest are fine */
    /* ... */
```

Comment: Ok, awesome. Now it's building correctly from the command line with maven. But IntelliJ still isn't running the annotation processing, so the generated files never end up in gen/aa like they're supposed to. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @liftdeadtrees, yeah IntelliJ's IDE compiler is in-process, and I've had so many problems with it properly detecting annotations. Most of the time, I've had to edit the "Annotation Processors" as you've specified in the screenshot, and I've had to give the *complete path* to the JARs, and not the relative paths. Try also checking "Obtain processors from project classpath" to see if that works...

Comment: I don't even know if this is what you meant, but I switched the path to the jars from ~/.m2/rest/of/path to /Users/matthewbbishop/.m2/rest/of/path and now for some exceedingly odd reason it's working. I'm super grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That's weird. You maven configuration seems great. It should, at least, compile fine via Maven...
I don't think it's this because the error should be different, but did you update to the last Android SDK 22 ?

Comment: I just updated, but the problem is still there. I added the R.java stub from the gen folder at the end of my question. I'm not sure if that's how IntelliJ is supposed to work, or if that is causing the issue with AndroidAnnotations?